# Linear function $f$ and the existence of constant M depending of $f$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-transformations

If $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear map, show that there exists a $M$, such that $|f(x)| \leq M|x|,$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^m.$

I guess $M$ depending of matrix associated with $f$, but I tried this way bellow.

It's trivial if $x=0$, eigenvector, or $f = 0$. For otherwise

let $y \neq 0$,  $y \not \in \ker f$ (exists because $f\neq 0)$ then

$|f(x)|=|f(x + |x|y - |x|y)| = |f(x) + |x| f(y) + (-|x|f(y))| \leq $

$\leq |f(x)| + ||x|f(y)| + |-|x|f(y)| = |f(x)| + |x||2f(y)| = |x|\left|\frac{f(x)}{|x|}+ 2f(y)\right|.$

Call $M= \left|\frac{f(x)}{|x|}+ 2f(y)\right|$.

It's ok?

Comment: No, $M$ should not depend on $x$ nor on $y$.

Comment: ok, can you give me a tip?

Comment: you can use the triangle inequality to bound norm of the image in function of the norm evaluated in some basis vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, for example, the max-norm.
Let $(e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_n)$ denote the canonical basis (where $e_i$ has exactly one non-zero entry equal to $1$).
Then we write
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i f(e_i)
$$
$$
|| f(x) ||_{\infty} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} | x_i | || f(e_i) ||_{\infty}
$$
and
$$
|| f(x) ||_{\infty}
\leq
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} || f(e_i) ||_{\infty} \right) || x ||_{\infty}
$$

Comment: he asked for a hint, not for a proof

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Show that  $f$ and $|\cdot|$ are continuous.
2. Consider the compact set  $S^{m-1}=\{x\in\Bbb R^m\mid |x|=1\}$ and the map  $|\cdot|\circ f:S^{m-1}\to \Bbb R_{\geq0} $. Since  $|\cdot|\circ f$ is a continuous map on a compact set, it is bounded. In other words, there exists some $M\gt0$ such that $|f (x)|\leq M $ whenever  $|x|=1$.
3. For $y\neq0\in\Bbb R^m $, consider  $x=\frac y {|y|}\in S^{m-1}$.